# Javascript innerHTML with form

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to move between pages, but when I try to go to the next page it does not work as expected. When I click it the first time the result is 01 instead of 1, and the second time it becomes 011 instead of 2. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**:

```
<p id='page'>0</p>
<div id='pics'>
    <a href='<?=URL;?>index.php?p=gallery&image=<?=$pic['album_pic_id'];?>'>
        <img class='<?php if($pic['album_pic_id'] == $image) 
            { echo "selected_pic"; } ?>' width='90px' height='60px'
            src='<?=URL;?>images/albums/<?=$pic['album_pic_photo'];?>' />
     </a>
     <a onclick='getElementById("page").value = getElementById("page").value+1;'>
         Pievienot
     </a>
 </div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var page = 0;
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to obfuscate your code?

Comment: The problem you describe and the code you show don't match up.  That code won't ever result in `01` or `011` being displayed.

Comment: You should be using a span or button for the A element with the click listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` and parse its content to an integer with `parseInt`:

```
<a onclick='getElementById("page").innerHTML = parseInt(getElementById("page").innerHTML) + 1;'>Pievienot</a>
```

`value` only works with `form` elements such as `input`.